# How to display results in two columns using PHP?

Tags: php, dreamweaver

I trying to display the product details into 2 columns.

At the moment, my below PHP is displaying as a single columm. Can someone please help? Thanks

Brand A  Brand B

Brand C  Brand D

not

Brand A

Brand B

Brand C

Brand D

---

```
    <?php 
    $count = 0;

    while($record = mysql_fetch_array($results)){
    $id = $record["prod_id"];
    $brand = $record["prod_brand"];
    $name = $record ["prod_name"];
    $nameC = $record ["prod_name_c"];
    $price = $record ["prod_price"];

    if($count % 2 <> 0) {

    extract($record);

    echo '<td class="itemHotDesc" id="bfTable3" valign="top"><a href="productDetail.php?id='.$id.'"><img src="admin/img/' . $id . '.jpg" class="itemImgborder" /></td>';
    echo '</tr>';
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td class="itemHotDesc" align="center">';
    echo $brand;
    echo '</br>';
    echo $name;
    echo '</br>';
    echo $nameC;
    echo '</br>';
    echo 'Special: US$'.$price;
    echo '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';      
    echo '<tr>';
    echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
    echo '</tr>';
    }
    else
    {
    echo '<td class="itemHotDesc" id="bfTable3" valign="top"><a href="productDetail.php?id='.$id.'"><img src="admin/img/' . $id . '.jpg" class="itemImgborder" /></td>';
    echo '</tr>';
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td class="itemHotDesc" align="center">';
    echo $brand;
    echo '</br>';
    echo $name;
    echo '</br>';
    echo $nameC;
    echo '</br>';
    echo 'Speical: US$'.$price;
    echo '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';      
    echo '<tr>';
    echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
    echo '</tr>';
    }
    $count++;   
}
```

?>

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not PHP related, but HTML related.

To have a table with multiple columns, you need to have a `<table>` element and one `<tr>` element per row that you want to have. In each `<tr>` you need to have one `<td>` element per **column** that you want to have.

If you have just one `<td>` in each `<tr>`, you will not get multiple columns.

Here is an example of a table with multiple columns:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>This is row 1, Column 1</td>
        <td>This is row 1, Column 2</td>
        <td>This is row 1, Column 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>This is row 2, Column 1</td>
        <td>This is row 2, Column 2</td>
        <td>This is row 2, Column 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>This is row 3, Column 1</td>
        <td>This is row 3, Column 2</td>
        <td>This is row 3, Column 3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This should give you something like

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| This is row 1, Column 1 | This is row 1, Column 2 | This is row 1, Column 3 |
|-------------------------|-------------------------|-------------------------|
| This is row 2, Column 1 | This is row 2, Column 2 | This is row 2, Column 3 |
|-------------------------|-------------------------|-------------------------|
| This is row 3, Column 1 | This is row 3, Column 2 | This is row 2, Column 3 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```